# Is there a case where i may align a statement with while loop, or put it inside a while loop as a suite, although results are the same?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
numlist = []
while True:
    number = input('Give me a number: ')
    if number == 'done':
        print(sum(numlist) / len(numlist))
        break
    else:
        x = int(number)
        numlist.append(x)
```

VS

```
numlist = []
while True:
    number = input('Give me a number: ')
    if number == 'done':
        break
    else:
        x = int(number)
        numlist.append(x)
print(sum(numlist) / len(numlist))
```

In this case: I tried moving the `print` statement around, inside as suite, and outside the `while` loop.

I see that the results are same but is there any case that I should use one for a certain cases?

Comment: As far as I can see (unless I'm missing something) both code samples do exactly the same and it only comes down to personal preference where you want to put the print statement.

Comment: I would suggest the first example as it is more readable, as you can see more clearly the cause of calling the print statement.

Comment: btw: if the user inputs something other than a number or `'done'` you will get an error, so unless this is only for you personally you should probably add additional checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same and there's no possible difference in the running time of both also. It totally depends on one's preferences what one would like to use.

For example:
I can do this in this way also and there are many other ways:

```
numlist = []
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input('Give me a number: '))
        numlist.append(number)
    except:
        break
        
print(sum(numlist) / len(numlist))
```